# Mail Queue getting huge even though mails are sent but slow and sending without spamassassin does not work

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, email-server

I have setup an Ubuntu 20.04 server to only use SMTP and send email from this server, but I am facing an issue that when `spamassassin` is stopped, `postfix` does not try to send anything, while when `spamassassin` is enabled I see mail queue is decreasing and postfix logs show me the sending.

Also when it's sending, send rate and speed is slow, about 1 to 10 per minute, while I did not set any limits and I checked `/etc/postfix/main.conf` and there was nothing to limit.

I see no errors in `/var/log/mail.err` and nothing happens in `/var/log/mail.log` when `spamassassin` is not enabled.

Would you please help me?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  If your goal is to remove `spamassassin` then take it out of the filter/milter chain in `main.cf` or `master.cf`.

Comment: Yes, I did comment the lines related to `spamd` and now all my emails are being sent without issue. They all have been delivered (except not existed users).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out and that was due to slow DNS resolving problem of the server.

It took around even 5 minutes to send a single email to Gmail.

I fixed it by changing the location of the server to another place.

Comment: you can also change the DNS to yourself, but remind to isntall a DNs first :)

Comment: @djdomi that's an old question and I resolved it by changing the location of the server:) because the country I used first, has some network issue unfortunately:(